# Firebase showing wrong number of users (as my app isn't released)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I just implemented Firebase into my Android app, and my dashboard is showing that I have 9 active users. I know it's wrong though, since the app isn't released, and I'm the only one who's used it.

I've kept it on the same device the whole time - I've run it with different version suffixes like `-debug` - but the package name has stayed the same. I assume that using a debug build, then a release build shouldn't inflate the number either

Does anyone know why this is, I thought Firebase used device IDs, but maybe I'm wrong? Or is it just state sponsored hackers that decided they liked my app ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase counts app  installed on a device, not a physical users. If you uninstall and reinstall the app on the same device, the device will be counted as two distinct users. The reason to define "user" this way is that the device ID is now always available on all mobile devices and on iOS in some cases its not available at all. On Android, non-Play enabled devices (most phones in China for example) do not provide device id. To keep the definition the same on all platforms the user is defined as app installed on device.

Comment: Ahh, I have reinstalled the app a few times to ensure a clean install. I'll just clear data from now on. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem, isn't there a way to get around this and only track unique users? My case is for a SaaS where the users are pretty much grouped in the same region with the same requirements. No restrictions or exceptions whatsoever.